# Filter out comments when writing Properties to a file

Tags: java, properties

I am using `java.util.Properties#store()` method to save my properties to a file:

```
os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(propertiesFile));
properties.store(os, null);
```

Default implementation of this method always writes comment as the first line with current `timestamp`:

```
#Thu May 16 12:55:36 EDT 2013
```

This behavior is not desired in my application as I need to track all changes in my properties file. Is it possible to filter this comment line (and all others) from property file somehow?

I am particularly interested in "on the fly" solution without post processing of the file afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can :).

First, you can extend `Properties` and override `store()` method. But this way is too complicated.

You can do better. Examine source code of `store()`. It calls private method `store()` that actually does the work. This method calls

`bw.write("#" + new Date().toString());`

in the beginning. You do not want to see this line. This means that you have to implement your own `BufferedWriter` that ignores the first printed line.

```
public class IgnoreFirstLineBufferedWriter extends BufferedWriter {
    private int lineCouner = 0;
    // constructors - implement them yourself

    @Override
    public void write(String str) throws IOException {
        if (lineCounter > 0) {
            super.write(str);
        }
        lineCounter++;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this customized `BufferedWriter` when you are wrapping your `FileOutputStream` and calling `store()`:

`props.store(new IgnoreFirstLineBufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("myprops.properties"))));`

Comment: this will work fine unless we pass non-null second parameter to store method. not my case, but it would be good to improve it

Answer (score 0):

This timestamp is printed in private method on Properties and there is no property to control that behaviour. If you want to change this behavior then you may need to subclass Properties, overwrite store method and copy/paste the content of the store0 method so that the date comment will not be printed.

Comment: I do not want to reinvent the wheel, there are too much code for encoding property names and values

Comment: Other approach will be then, to delete the first line from the newly created properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Date is not printed when you use storeToXML method. But properties will be stored in XML(
Otherwise the best way to do it is to extend Properties class as explained before